# Группировка в SQL - запросе в Sping Data проекте Java настойчиво требует id

Tags: java, sql, group-by, spring-data

Ситуация:
Делаю проект на Java, Spring Framework.
Использую БД:

```
spring:
   datasource:
     driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
     url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

Есть таблица:

```
create table buyproducts (
   id                  bigserial primary key,
   product_id          bigint not null,
   product_name        varchar(255),
   product_date        date,
   product_quantity    int,
   created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
   updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

В репозитории создаю запрос:

```
@Query("select b from BuyProduct b group by b.productName order by b.productName")
List<BuyProduct> findFive();
```

После запуска и обращения с фронта к этому запросу, выкидывается следующее:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Столбец "BUYPRODUCT0_.ID" должен быть в предложении GROUP BY Column "BUYPRODUCT0_.ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement: select buyproduct0_.id as id1_0_, buyproduct0_.created_at as created_2_0_, buyproduct0_.product_date as product_3_0_, buyproduct0_.product_id as product_4_0_, buyproduct0_.product_name as product_5_0_, buyproduct0_.product_quantity as product_6_0_, buyproduct0_.updated_at as updated_7_0_ from buyproducts buyproduct0_ group by buyproduct0_.product_name order by buyproduct0_.product_name [90016-200]
```

и так далее... стэктрейс исключений.

Пробую запрос:

```
@Query(value = "select id, product_id, product_name, product_date, sum(product_quantity) as product_quantity, created_at, updated_at from buyproducts group by product_name, id;", nativeQuery = true)
List<BuyProduct> findFive();
```

Все проходит, исключений нет, но и ожидаемого результата - группировки по product_name нету (в выходных данных встречаются повторения названий).
Так что такой вариант работает, но результат не соответствует моим ожиданиям.

Чтобы обойти id пробую такой запрос:

```
 @Query(value = "select * from (select product_name, product_quantity from buyproducts) as vyb group by product_name;", nativeQuery = true)
List<BuyProduct> findFive();
```

Теперь выкидывает исключение такого плана:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Столбец "id" не найден Column "id" not found [42122-200]
```

ну и далее список ... стэктрейс исключений.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за такая зацикленность у группировки на id?

Возможно ли в этой ситуации с ней как-то справиться, чтобы получить группировку по полю product_name?

Comment: Что вы ожидаете в результате запроса типа "select b from BuyProduct b group by b.productName" получить? Я спрашиваю потому, что такой запрос не имеет смысла. Вы, очевидно, неверно представляете, как работает group by. Сообщения об ошибках следствие того, что запрос не имеет смысла. Объяснити словами, что запрос должен возвращать

Comment: Благодарю, Роман!
Как говориться: "Слона то я и не заметил, а ларчик просто открывался" )
Сделал:
    @Query("select b.productName, sum(b.productQuantity) from BuyProduct b group by b.productName order by b.productName")
Запрос проходит!